# Optimization with interrupts or threads and global variables

Tags: c, multithreading, interrupt, volatile

I find that I have some difficulty with how to best write communication between functions that are out of the normal flow of code. A simple example is:

```
int a = 0;
volatile int v = 0;

void __attribute__((used)) interrupt() {
    a++;
    v++;
}

int main() {
    while(1) {
        // asm("nop");
        a--;
        v--;
        if (v > 10 && a > 10)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is not surprising that the main while loop can optimize the `a` variable to a register and thus never see any changes from the interrupt. If the variable is volatile then it is annoying in that every time it is used in needs to be reread from or rewritten to memory. And in that technique any communication variable across threads would need to be volatile. A synchronization primitive (or even the commented out "nop") solves the problem because it seemingly has a side effect to create a compiler barrier. But if I understand correctly that would mean flushing the entire state of all the registers used in main, where maybe it's less harsh to just have a few variables as volatile. I currently use the two techniques but I wish I had a more standard method for dealing with the issue. Can anyone comment on best strategies here?

[A link to some assembly](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:11),source:%27int+a+%3D+0%3B%0Avolatile+int+v+%3D+0%3B%0A%0Avoid+__attribute__((used))+interrupt()+%7B%0A++++a%2B%2B%3B%0A++++v%2B%2B%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++while(1)+%7B%0A++++++++//asm(%22nop%22)%3B%0A++++++++a--%3B%0A++++++++v--%3B%0A++++++++if+(v+%3E+10+%26%26+a+%3E+10)%0A++++++++++++break%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:59.11169170476812,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g103,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-flto%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.3+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:40.88830829523188,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:65.82466567607726,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+10.3+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:34.17533432392273,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score 0):

So you want a means of reducing the number of times `a` is looked up. The following reduces it to once a loop:

```c
volatile int a = 0;
volatile int v = 0;

void __attribute__((used)) interrupt() {
    a++;
    v++;
}

int main() {
    while(1) {
        int b = --a;
        --v;
        if (v > 10 && b > 10)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing stops you from checking even less often similarly.

Comment: what if a will change ? Program will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @0___________ According to the OP, `volatile` should handle that. Is that not the case?

Comment: `b > 10` b is no volatile and a could have changed.

Comment: @0___________, So? That's the whole point. The questions was specifically about reading `a` less often. The fact that the change will only be caught on the next loop pass is not a problem. It's actually the desired effect.